# How can I effectively weight different fields when performing an internal site search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am implementing an internal search that looks at various normalized fields to determine relevance for a user's search terms. The `best_fields` strategy seems to yield strange results sometimes because a "less important" field will generate the highest score and beat out other more important fields with weaker matches. I've included a `boost`, but cranking that value up seems like it will also skew results; as does moving to a `most_fields` strategy since not all pages will have all the fields.

What is the right way to go about tuning the below query & incorporating scores from each field?

Below is an example where the `content` field ends up winning the "max" evaluation for `best_field` (because the search term is present more times) and scores higher than the second page which I want to come first because the search term is a literal match for the `keywords` field. What's more, since more keywords are added to important pages, their match seems to get further devalued since the field length is much longer than average.

Query Example

```
{
    "query": {
        'multi_match' : {
            "query": "Hello World",
            "fields": ["keywords^3", "name^2", "content^1"]
        }
    }
};
```

Document/Results Example:

```
[{
    "name": "Howdy!",
    "keywords: "",
    "content": "Hello everybody, I'm in the world. hello there, i like saying hello"
},{
    "name": "Hey",
    "keywords: "Hello World, Hello, World",
    "content": "Lot's of text, Lot's of text, Lot's of text, Lot's of text, Lot's of text, Hello"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have right now is static boost which is also a good way to tune the search relevance but for advance use cases like yours I would advise looking at [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) way to fine tuning the score and relevance.

Please go through at the function score documentation, its quite exhaustive and can easily serve your use-case.